# Having difficulty importing emscripten wasm c++ class into svelte component

Tags: javascript, module, svelte, webassembly, emscripten

I've been trying to use my c++ class in my svelte component, and been beating my head against the screen for the past week trying to figure out how to do this. I'm comfortable in c++ but not so much in JS, which I suspect is part of the issue.
My c++ code is :

```
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;
using emscripten::val;
using namespace std;
thread_local const val document = val::global("document");

class MyClass{
  private :
  val canvas;
  val ctx;
  public :
MyClass(std::string id){
  canvas = val::global("document").call<val>("getElementById", val(id));
  ctx = canvas.call<val>("getContext", val("2d") );}

void greenRect(){
   emscripten_run_script("alert('greenrect')");
   ctx.set("fillStyle", "green");
   ctx.call<void>("fillRect", 10, 10, 150, 100);
 }
 ~MyClass(){}};

  EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(MyClassModule) {
   class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
     .constructor< std::string>()
     .function("greenRect", &MyClass::greenRect)
     ;}
```

In this example my life would probably be easier if I just switched to a C++ function rather than a class, but I would like to keep it as a class unless this is completely non-viable (which it shouldn't be).
My current invocation of the compiler is `em++ -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -lembind -s USE_SDL=2 -s ENVIRONMENT='web'  -s SINGLE_FILE=1 chart.cpp -o glue.js`

The script portion of the App.svelte component is

```
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import { MyClass } from "../em/glue.js";
  onMount(async () => {
    alert("pre");
    const chart = new Module.MyClass("canvas0");
    alert("post");
    chart.greenRect();
  });
```

I get the "pre" popup but never the "post" popup.

I've tried several variations on the `import` statement with   `import MyClass from 'glue.js'`, `<script src ="glue.js">` in the `svelte:header` section. I've also tried a variety of CLI options including`-s MODULARIZE=1,  -s EXPORT_ES6=1,-s EXPORT_ALL=1, -s WASM=1`  none of which seem to fix this issue.

The problem is that I keep getting errors in the browser
`import { MyClass } from 'glue.js'` -> "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: MyClass"
`import * as MyClass from 'glue.js'` -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Module.MyClass is not a constructor
`import MyClass from 'glue.js'` -> `Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default`
I've also changed the `const chart = new MyClass("canvas0")` to `const chart = new Module.MyClass("canvas0");` and `const chart = new MyClass.MyClass("canvas0");`

Yup, JS is not my strong point and I'm admittedly just throwing stuff at the wall to see what sticks.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. I tried to get chatGPT and Bard to fix the issue and have come away feeling confident that coders' jobs are secure for the foreseeable future.

I appreciate any help you can give.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem - for some reason I have to add `echo 'export { Module };' >> glue.js` after which i change the svelte code to

```
import { Module } from "../glue.js";
onMount(async () => {
    Module.onRuntimeInitialized = async () => {         
alert("pre");
      const chart = new Module.MyClass("canvas0");                                                       alert("post");                                    chart.greenRect();                              };                                              });
```

Now everything runs as expected.